# Conditional Filtering on Report Data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a table entry for multiple Product and Many different features. All the data has date time in shown format.

[image]

As we can see that all products has entries across different time. My aim is to filter the details related to the product by latest time of everyday.

I was able to split the Time col in Date col & Time col separately.

Comment: might not be the best solution but you can try and use groupby in power query and then use list.last to get the latest/last value for each group  after sorting the data based on that date&time column.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating a new table in Dax for eg. (because I don't know what do you want to do with rows with the same timestamp I show both rows for C)

[image]

```
YourFilteredTable =
VAR __trt =
    TREATAS (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    ADDCOLUMNS (
                        ALL ( YourTable[Product], YourTable[Time] ),
                        "day", DATEVALUE ( YourTable[Time] )
                    ),
                    YourTable[Product],
                    [day]
                ),
                "MaxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( YourTable[Time] ) )
            ),
            "Prod", [Product],
            "MaxDate", [MaxDate]
        ),
        YourTable[Product],
        YourTable[Time]
    )
RETURN
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        YourTable[Product],
        YourTable[Quant],
        YourTable[Time],
        __trt
    )
```